# Doesn't render my data as graph format in DJango

Tags: python, django

I am new to dJango and I want to visualize my data which is stored on database in django.
By following the tutorial on the website, I successfully implemented the code which allows me to store the data into database.
Next step is to visualize the data into html web pages.
I tried it but failed to visualize it. I can only see the json format string that is not the graph format.

Here is my django code.

***urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form/$', views.play_count_by_month),
    url(r'^api/play_count_by_month', views.play_count_by_month, name='playAround'),
    # url(r'^form/$',views.Form),
    url(r'^upload/$',views.upload_file_name),
]
```

***views.py***

```
def play_count_by_month(request):
    data = Data.objects.all() \
        .extra(select={'c1': connections[Data.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('c1', 'c2')}) \
        .values('c2') \
        .annotate(count_items=Count('c1'))
    return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Data(models.Model):
    c1=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4)
    c2=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4)
    c3=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4)
    c4=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4)
    c5=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.c1
```

*** form.html ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse; // for dates like "2014-01-01"
//var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z").parse;  // for dates like "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.c2); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count_items); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("{% url "play_count_by_month" %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.c2 = parseDate(d.c2);
    d.count_items = +d.count_items;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.c1; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.c2; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Play count");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The only I can see is the json format data as below, which is not graph typ e in the html web page.

```
[{"c2": "1.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "2.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "3.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "4.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "5.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "6.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "7.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "8.0000", "count_items": 4},  {"c2": "191.0000", "count_items": 4}, {"c2": "192.0000", "count_items": 4}]
```

Comment: I don't think this is a Django quesiton.

Comment: Fellow Alex, I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

This is what will be shown to the user because this is all that was returned by the function. Your script is never even downloaded, let alone run. Django isn't just going to serve the template you made just because the name matches your URL.

What you want is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

# instead of the JsonResponse in your view
return render(request, 'form.html', {'json': json.dumps(data)})
```

This will 'render' your HTML with 'json' as a Django Template Language variable. We use json.dumps to convert it to the expected format, which appears to be a json string.

Then, in the template wherever your script wants it (or even as a javascript variable)

```
{{ json }}
```

example:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
    var jsondata = {{ json }}
```

This will essentially "print" the content of the variable directly into the HTML at the specified location. After that, it can be used by the script. I'm not familiar with the d3 library but I can help out there possibly too.

---

The underlying concept here is that what you *return* in your view function is wrapped up in some headers and such, then sent to the user as a literal string of text. Your JsonResponse is making your data into a string, adding the headers, and then just sending it straight to the client.

The render function takes the file you specify, "renders" it into a nice long string by substituting out the {{ Django Tempate code }} with the variables you specify in the dictionary object, then passes that on to the client. So:

```
render(request, 'some.html', {'bacon': 'Eggs'})
```

with template

```
{{ bacon }}
```

will send the client

```
Eggs
```

Hopefully that makes sense. If you're this far in then you should be close to mastering the basics of Django and request and response. The documentation for Django is great, but requires a bit of vocabulary and tenacity, so I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I followed your advice and changed the code as you suggested. However, I got the following error "Object of type 'QuerySet' is not JSON serializable". Could you help me more?

Comment: You need to load the queryset into a json for your script, so you need to do some fiddling of the QuerySet object. Instead of passing it in like above, convert it to json with something like this:

import json
json.dumps(your_variable_name.values())

In short we're trying to muscle the data into a json format. Again, the proper way to do this is with an AJAX request, but if you're not quite there yet, then you can fudge it with something like the above code. (Fudging it is more complicated than doing it the right way.)